# Ubuntu 16.04 job on crontab not executed

Tags: 16.04, bash, cron, mongodb

Can someone help me how to debug my cron job cause it doesn't work.

```
00 02 * * * /bin/bash /home/user/directory/cron-mongodb.sh >> /home/user/debug-cron-mongodb.txt 2>&1
```

I want it to start at 2 AM.
`sudo service cron status` is active
I edit the file using `crontab -e`

`sudo cat /var/log/syslog` outputs:

```
Sep 30 00:19:01 <hostname> CRON[32601]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 30 00:45:42 <hostname> systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Sep 30 00:45:42 <hostname> systemd-tmpfiles[1007]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log", ignoring.
Sep 30 00:45:42 <hostname> systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Sep 30 01:19:01 <hostname> CRON[2080]: (root) CMD (cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Sep 30 01:42:42 <hostname> systemd[1]: Started Session 10894123 of user <user>.
```

Comment: look into /var/log/syslog. What does it says?

Comment: @janasaiarun I updated the post, see above

Answer (score 0):

you need to replace

```
<user>
```

with the appropriate user as well as

```
<path>
```

needs to be replaced with the path to cron-mongodb.sh within home directory of the user you specified above

Comment: Just write it as an example. I use real path in my cron file.